# How to add dark mode support to Baidu map (For china region) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, darkmode, baidu-map

I need to add dark mode support in my application which uses Baidu map for china region and i am unable to find any styling which can be added to achieve the required target, thanks in advance !!